# How to get the row id of a particular selected row?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have added two `TableRows` to `TableLayout` that is in a for loop. In every first `TableRow` there are 6 `TextViews` and 1 `ImageView` & 1 Toggle Button. I have added an `OnClickListener` to the `first row` & Toggle Button. My question is in the `onclick` method for the `First Row`, how should I get the row id of that particular selected row?

Can someone help me?

Plz help me.....

I want to get the row id of a particular selected row......

Plz anyone reply me....

Comment: Try to better explain what are you trying to do. You say that you set a onclick listener for the first row(only for this row?) and you want to know the particular selected row(the only row that could be selected is the first one that has the listener set on it, so how is it?!?!)? Post the code where you setup the `TableLayout` and `TableRows`.

Comment: Why I am setting the onclick listener for the first row is, I want to get the value of 2nd textview as well as I want to know the particular selected row id also....

Comment: You're not making any sense. How another row, besides the first row, could be selected if you only set a `OnCLickListener` for the first one? How would you be able to see that the user selected a `TableRow` if it doesn't have a listener attached to it? **ADD** the code where you create the `TableLayout` and `TableRow`.

Comment: Is there any mistake, please let me know. I have to resolve that issue.... Please reply me....

Comment: Thanks for you reply... I will try with this soln..:)

Answer (score 4):

Navigate through the `View` hierarchy in the `ImageView` `OnCLickListener` like this:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onCLick(View v) {
          // v represents the view that was clicked(the ImageView)
          // if the ImageView is added directly to the TableRow then you could simply do
          TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent(); // if the ImageView isn't a direct child of the TableRow then walk through all the parent with getParent().
          // do stuff 
     }

});
```

**Edit :**

Your code doesn't help and by looking at what you're doing  I would advise you to start with something a little simpler to learn about android. Also, `tabLayout.addView(openedRow1, n_D);` doesn't add a tag to the *openedRow1* `View`(if this is what you want to do), it just position that `View` to the specific position in the parent(like `0` to be the first child of the parent).

I would guess that you're trying to get the text from the second `TextView`( **tv_vin_val** ?!?!) when it's parent is clicked. If this is all you want to do then try something like this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        // you set the listener on the TableRow so v is the TableRow that was clicked 
        TableRow lTableRow = ((TableRow) v);                                
        // to get the TextView use getChildAt or findViewById
        TextView lTextView = (TextView)lTableRow.getChildAt(1);
        //get the text from the TextView  
        vinNum = lTextView.getText().toString();
        // the tag
        int theTag = (Integer) v.getTag();          
        Intent intent = new Intent(DeliveryInspectionActivity.this, ExceptionsActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("row id value", theTag);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }
```

Comment: Haha, nice, beat me to it. :) +1

Comment: tabLayout.addView(openedRow1, theTag);
     tabLayout.addView(openedRow2, theTag);, when i add this I am getting NullPointerException, openedRow1 and openedRow2 are the rows in onactivityresult

Comment: @Geetha I can't debug the app for you. I advise you to learn about android layouts before you attempt any major app construction like you're currently trying to do, you're missing some notions about how layouts and views are working in android.

Comment: ok, if u dont mind, can u please suggest me which layouts i have to use for my requirement

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain how you would get the correct row number for that, but what I would suggest instead is to use the `getParent()` method of `View` to get a reference to the `TableRow` containing the image and work directly from that. Something like this:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow)v.getParent();
        //handle your stuff here
    }
});
```